Difficulty detecting peak points in PSD graph using derivative method
I'm working on a signal processing task where I need to detect peak points in a Power Spectral Density (PSD) graph within specific frequency ranges (Freqs[0] to Freqs[2]). I'm using Python and calculating the derivative to find where the slope changes from positive to negative, which I expect to correspond to peaks. However, my code doesn't seem to reliably catch the peaks, especially within the regions where I've plotted red, green, and blue lines on the graph. It is okay the peak is in range of +- 0.2Hz in Freqs[0] to Freqs[2]
Here's the PSD graph I'm working with:

Here's a simplified version of my code:
def diff_f(f, a):
    return (f[a+1] - f[a]) / 0.2  # a is the index corresponding to the frequency

find_peak = []

# Example of detecting a peak around Freqs[0]
if diff_f(f1, int(round((Freqs[0] / 0.2)) - 1)) > 0 and diff_f(f1, int(round((Freqs[0] / 0.2)))) < 0:
    find_peak.append(Freqs[0]) # (Freqs[0] / 0.2) 0.2 is Frequency Resolution of FFT

# Similar checks for Freqs[1], Freqs[2], and other combinations

Is there an issue with my derivative calculation method for detecting peaks?
A simple threshold value peak-detection algorithm does not work, because the noise in the first section has the same amplitude as the peak later on.

Welcome to SO! Can you clarify what results you get from the code you have, and how they differ from what you want?

Also, you mention that the noise in some areas has the same amplitude as the peaks in other areas. If that's the case, then I don't really know from your picture where the "real" peaks are and what's just high amplitude noise. Can you clarify?

Why did you go with the derivative method to detect the peaks? You can use scipy.signal.find_peaks or z-score peak transformation. My experience in taking derivatives is that it only works where data is coming from an expecte pattern, e.g. a moving car or the power consumption of a machine. Where is your data coming from? How is it measured?
